# Help learning OpenLayers for D7

Tags: 7, location, javascript

I need to learn more about OpenLayers for Drupal 7. There is a ton of documentation for D6, some of which is helpful and some which isn't.

I'd like advice or suggestions for tutorials for a few different pieces..

When creating content, I want users to add a point or an area using a map. I know this is GeoField with the OpenLayers Map widget (so they don't type anything, but select visually), but I'm not sure how to then use this data in views.

In views, I need to create a map that displays the content. I want to set the default area based on the users' location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best tutorial I'm aware of: http://www.istos.it/blog/mapping/openlayers-and-addressfieldis

Answer (score 2):

The [Drupal 7 Getting Started Guide](http://drupal.org/node/1481374) has been started, but still needs some love.  A good place to begin (and add to the wiki as you go along).

Answer (score -1):

this is very good: http://www.syntux.nl/blog/basic-setup-drupal-7-openlayers-geofield-views-3.html